# min and count without limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I need to select a receipt with 3 conditions:

1. total receipt > 50 (receipt.total)
2. associated purchases doesn't include item "cucumbers" (product.pname)
3. the number of suppliers (product.sid) of associated products is the lowest

I have the following tables set up:

```
Receipt (bid, rdate, rtime, ptype, total)
Purchase (bid, rdate, rtime, code, units)
Product (code, pname, descr, utype, uprice, manu, sid)
```

sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Product (code, pname, descr, utype, uprice, manu, sid) VALUES
        (987, 'Tomatoes',       'Vegetable',  'Kg',  5.99,  'manufacturer1', 111),
        (876, 'Cucumbers',      'Vegetable',  'Kg',  4.99,  'manufacturer2', 222),
        (765, 'Cornflakes',     'Cornflakes', 'Box', 15.9,  'manufacturer2', 222),
        (654, 'Camembert',      'Cheese',     'Box', 12.50, 'manufacturer2', 111),
        (543, 'sweet potato',   'Vegetable',  'Kg',  16.40, 'manufacturer3', 333),
        (432, 'red pepper',     'Vegetable',  'Kg',  15.99, 'manufacturer1', 111);
INSERT INTO Receipt (bid, rdate, rtime, ptype, total) VALUES
        (989, '18/3/2020', '10:00', 'Cash', 126.51),
        (989, '16/7/2020', '12:30', 'Credit',0),
        (989, '15/7/2020', '15:35', 'Credit',0),
        (878, '17/3/2020', '8:30',  'Cash', 60.47),
        (878, '22/7/2020', '7:00',  'Credit',0),
        (767, '13/7/2020', '22:00', 'Cash',0),
        (767, '10/3/2020', '20:30', 'Cash',42.97),
        (767, '14/5/2020', '14:25', 'Credit',0);


INSERT INTO Purchase (bid, rdate, rtime, code, units) VALUES
        (989, '18/3/2020', '10:00', 987, 5),
        (989, '18/3/2020', '10:00', 876, 3),
        (989, '18/3/2020', '10:00', 543, 4),
        (989, '18/3/2020', '10:00', 432, 1),
        (878, '17/3/2020', '8:30',  654, 1),
        (878, '17/3/2020', '8:30',  432, 3),
        (767, '10/3/2020', '20:30', 654, 2),
        (767, '10/3/2020', '20:30', 987, 3);
```

So far I have the following but it is not getting the receipt with the lowest number of sid:

```
SELECT Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid
FROM Receipt NATURAL JOIN Purchase NATURAL JOIN Product
WHERE total > 50 and 
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Purchase
    WHERE Receipt.bid = Purchase.bid and Receipt.rdate = Purchase.rdate and Receipt.rtime = Purchase.rtime and Product.code = '876')
GROUP BY Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product.sid) = (SELECT MIN(mycount) 
FROM (SELECT sid,COUNT(DISTINCT Product.sid) mycount from product group by product.sid) ct);
```

I'm not allowed to use order by and limit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider using meaningful column names.

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd condition do you mean number as in count or lowest sid, please add expected output.

Comment: which db you are really using ??  mysql or postgresql  ???

Comment: I'm using postgresql. I need to get the receipt with minimum count of unique sid. the expected output with the sample data would be "878, '17/3/2020', '8:30'" since this receipt only have 1 sid associated

Comment: How do you define what a receipt is?  What results do you want?  You have no column in your tables called `total`, so your query should fail.

Comment: as result i need to get (Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid) from table receipt of which contains 1 line with the lowest count of distinct sid values (from product table)

Comment: I've added total values that was missing

Comment: *I'm not allowed to use order by and limit.* Why? Gordon's Order By/Limit  in a can be replaced by a Row_Number = 1

Comment: The assignment i received is to not use it unfortunately. Row_Number = 1 same idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without ORDER BY:

```
with cte as 
 ( SELECT Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid,
      COUNT(DISTINCT Product.sid) as cnt, -- count per bid
      MIN(COUNT(DISTINCT Product.sid))    -- minimum count over rows
      OVER () as min_count                -- PARTITION BY needed???
   FROM Receipt NATURAL JOIN Purchase NATURAL JOIN Product
   WHERE total > 50 and 
   NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Purchase
       WHERE Receipt.bid = Purchase.bid
         and Receipt.rdate = Purchase.rdate
         and Receipt.rtime = Purchase.rtime and Product.code = '876')
   GROUP BY Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid
 )
select *
from cte
where cnt = min_count
```

Simplifying the NOT EXISTS logic:

```
with cte as 
 ( SELECT Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid,
      COUNT(DISTINCT Product.sid) as cnt, -- count per bid
      MIN(COUNT(DISTINCT Product.sid))    -- minimum count over rows
      OVER () as min_count                -- PARTITION BY needed???
   FROM Receipt NATURAL JOIN Purchase NATURAL JOIN Product
   WHERE total > 50 
   GROUP BY Receipt.rdate, Receipt.rtime, Receipt.bid
   -- will be > 0 when cucumbers exist
   HAVING count(case when product.pname = 'cucumbers' then 1 end) = 0
 )
select *
from cte
where cnt = min_count
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an aggregation query to me:

```
select p.bid, p.rdate, p.rtime, sum(pr.price * p.units), count(distinct pr.sid) as num_suppliers
from purchase p join
     products pr
     on pr.code = p.code
group by p.bid, p.rdate, p.rtime
having count(*) filter (where pr.name = 'cucumbers') = 0 and
       sum(pr.price * p.units) > 50
order by count(distinct pr.sid) asc
limit 1;
```

I see your data model does have a `total` but not your data.  In that case:

```
select p.bid, p.rdate, p.rtime, sum(pr.price * p.units), count(distinct pr.sid) as num_suppliers
from purchase p join
     products pr
     on pr.code = p.code join
     receipt r
     on r.bid = p.bid and r.rdate = p.rdate and r.rtime = p.rtime
where r.total > 50
group by p.bid, p.rdate, p.rtime
having count(*) filter (where pr.name = 'cucumbers') = 0 
order by count(distinct pr.sid) asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! but Im not allowed to use order by and limit (mentioned in the question...)